# Mysql date function for getting later of two dates

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I want to set column of DATE type by increasing other date column, but also making it no less than some other date (constant).

For 1st part I use:

```
UPDATE `customers` set `expiry_date` = DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL 3 YEAR)
```

Now I'm looking for some function like MAX(d1, d2) which would take later date of two.

I saw construct like this:

```
case when d1 > d2 then d1 else d2 end
```

Maybe it works, but it requires to type both d1/d2 two times.
Is not there function like MAX(d1,d2) which would evaluate each parameter once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you are looking but MySQL has `GREATEST` function whish returns the highest value on the list, eg.

```
SELECT GREATEST(1, 5, 2, 7, 10, 3)
```

will yield `10`.

- [GREATEST()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest)

Comment: Yes, you're my hero, that's what I needed! Tested, and it solved my task.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `GREATEST()` function?

If it doesn't work directly with dates, convert the dates to numbers first, then reconvert the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DATEDIFF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)

```
UPDATE `customers` 
set `expiry_date` = ( case  when DATEDIFF(d1,d2)<=0 
                            then d1
                            when DATEDIFF(d1,d2)>0 
                            then d2
                      end case
                    )
```

Comment: As I wrote, I wanted avoid multiple d1/d2, and you have them used 3 times.  GREATEST() function solved the task.